# Append Plus or Minus to jQuery Accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

For some strict rules about style, I am not supposed to use jquery ui css. Given this constraint, I have successfully implemented accordion using jQuery-UI. This is a part of list of items that I get in MVC Razor. So there are as many accordions as there are items (I'm using a foreach loop in my view). This is the reason, I am using a class name instead of the standard way of 'id=accordion'.

Thus my html:

```
<div class="accordion">
                        <h4><span class="panel-icon">+</span> Addresses</h4>
                        <div>
                            <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
                        </div>
</div>
```

and script:

```
<script>

    $(function () {
        $(".accordion").accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            active: false
        });


</script>
```

The point is to toggle the 's text to '-' or '+' as the case may be. How can I achieve this?

Comment: are you using jquery ui accordion

Comment: Yes I'm. Sorry for not mentioning. Editing the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass icon  like below in your function.If it accordion closed then pass as plus icon css in `header` properties.Again it open then pass minus icon in css `activeheader` properties

```
$(function () {
  icons = {
      header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-plus",
      activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-minus"
    };

        $(".accordion").accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            active: false,
        icons: icons
        });
});
```

Comment: This solutions seems to use jquery-ui css as given [here](https://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-icons). I cannot use this css due to some style restrictions.

Comment: You can call your own css.